# Where is project properties in android studio on mac?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio

I am trying get latitude and longitude from address, for I that I intend to use GeoPoint , it says GeoPoint cannot be resolved. I came across this. [Cannot import GeoPoint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000024/import-com-google-android-maps-geopoint-cannot-be-resolved) but I don't find any project properties in android studio on Mac,where is it? and how I do change from android x.x to Google API? Thank You.

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with the question, instead of down voting?

Comment: possible duplicate of [import com.google.android.maps.geopoint cannot be resolved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000024/import-com-google-android-maps-geopoint-cannot-be-resolved)

Comment: I just used that link in my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android Studio is different from Eclipse. Add the Google Play Services dependancy to your project. Follow the steps mentioned [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

Comment: I included google play services  compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.8.0' but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Well the you must be using the Android Google Maps API V2. Use a `LatLng` object instead.

Comment: Thanks!. I just used it. :).